# Jquery: error in parsing valid Json string with double quotes

Tags: jquery, json

I am puzzled by this. I read many posts on SO, but strangely I cannot find one solution for my situation.

I have the following very simple VALID json string. Note that it contains a double quote in attribute value.

```
{"text":"\"xxxxx"}
```

You can verify that it is a valid Json string at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Now I hope to parse the above string with jQuery.parseJSON into an **object** the following way:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"text":"\"xxxxx"}');
```

I get error. Can someone let me know what I miss?

Thanks a lot!!!

**Background**

I am doing a web application. In the backend (Java+Spring), I use Google's Gson to parse a complex object into a Json string. This string is then passed to the fontend (Javascript) as a string. Now I need to convert the string back into a Json object. I cannot change this technical approach.

**Update 1**
The following is actual code generated as part of the page when the page is load (I can see it in View Source in Firefox)

```
<script>
var data='{"defaultLocale":"en","answers":[{"text":"\"xxxx"}.......
</script>
```

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude already answered that. Before passing json to front end, escape backslashes: `json.replace('"', '\\"').replace('\\', '\\\\');`

Comment: @ankhzet, thanks for chiming in! Please see my response to MarcosPérezGude's answer.

Comment: You, probably, wrong. If you builded JSON in backend as `'{"text":"\"xxxxx"}'`, then to front-end it is delivered already broken: `'{"text":""xxxxx"}'`. It's can't be fixed at front-end side. show us code, where front-end receives the json, maybe we can debug it there to find out if it's true

Comment: @ankhzet, please see my update. The frontend javascript variable does have "\" when the page is load.

Comment: No, it isn't. `{"text":"\"xxxx"` will be translated by JS engine as `{"text":""xxxx"`. See, broken.

Comment: try to remove surrounding singlequote, so `data='{...}';` becomes `data={...};`

Comment: @ankhzet, removing singlequote solved the problem. This is really the best way in my case. Thanks a million. If you can post it as the answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with JSON-encoded object, injected into script as string and then JSON-decoded.

```
<script>
var data='{"defaultLocale":"en","answers":[{"text":"\"xxxx"} ... }';
</script>
```

So, as long as JSON-encoded object string has a valid javascript syntax (as intended, obviously), it can be injected directly, without string -> JSON-decode step:

```
<script>
var data = {"defaultLocale":"en","answers":[{"text":"\"xxxx"} ... };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is valid, but when you parse it the escape values are lost. This is the valid parse JSON:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"text":"\\\"xxxxx"}');
```

Comment: See my update to the post. The Json string actually is a lot more complex and I don't wish do this type of "\\" thing in the backend if there is a frontend solution . Thanks for your input!

Comment: You need to get in front end the valid json, you are receiving an invalid string. Share us your code as @ankhzet said in the post's coments